# Ajax - Spring send javascript object and accept as custom object.The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a custom class in java which is something like

```
    public class AddressesVO {

private Long addressId;
private String address;

public Long getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}
public void setAddressId(Long addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

and my spring function looks like this,

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/searchAddress", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String searchAddress(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody        AddressesVO abc) {
System.out.println("This is the AddressesVO  Object" +abc);
    }
```

i am doing an ajax call to the above function and passing an javascript object as data.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",  
url: "searchAddress/",
data: objname, 
success: function(){  
   alert('Form submitted');
            alert(response);
},
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert('failure'+response); 
}
```

});

but i am getting an error saying 
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect and its goign in fail

Can any one help me how do i send a JS object to spring and accept it as a custom class.

Comment: Let's see your `objname` structure.

Comment: You need to change the return type to be your object, include the Jackson lib, and Spring will auto-magically convert your object to JSON.  Then your success function needs to accept the proper object type (this looks like jQuery, so I think the signature is success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR))

Answer (score 0):

Create a javascript object
`var AddressesVO = new Object();`

Populate its fields

```
AddressesVO.addressId = 111;
AddressesVO.address = 'some address';
```

pass this object to ajax call (Note: data: AddressesVO)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "searchAddress/",
    data: AddressesVO, 
    success: function(){  
        alert('Form submitted');
        alert(response);
    },
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    alert('failure'+response); 
}
```

Change spring method (Note: @ModelAttribute AddressesVO)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchAddress", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public String searchAddress(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute AddressesVO abc) {
    System.out.println("This is the AddressesVO  Object" +abc);
}
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Doesn't the `data` need to be `JSON.stringified()` first in the AJAX request? And maybe set the `contentType` to `application/json` ... ?

Comment: @WildService it will work without `JSON.stringify() and application/json`. We are passing java object to spring method not json object and `@ModelAttribute` will populate java object.